# C++ passing variable number of locations from a given array to a function

Tags: c++, string, variadic-functions

The following piece of code works in C++ when running on Windows:

```
void* paramsList[MAX_PARAMS_NUM] = { 0 };

...some code to populate paramsList (p.s MAX_PARAMS_NUM is a constant)

vsnprintf((char*)pStr, MAXLEN, (char*)pTempFormat, (va_list)paramsList);
```

This code works fine on Windows, but i am trying to make it run on Linux and the program crushes because this conversion of `paramsList` to `va_list` doesn't work there.

Now the setting of this scenario is that i get a format string from a server that i don't control. The format string ('pTempFormat') is like the one used in printf of unknown number of % in it (maximum is `MAX_PARAMS_NUM`) and i populate the paramsList accordingly and then i use `vsnprintf` to create a string from the format string i got and the values populated in paramsList.(those values can be anything from integers, to hex to char * (aka strings) and any combination of them, according to the format string received from the server).

i don't know how many locations `paramsList` to pass to `vsnprintf` until i finish populating it according to the  format string received from the server. So i need to somehow either pass a variable number of locations from `paramsList`to `vsnprintf` or to convert those locations into va_list (which i couldn't figure out how to do from what i read online).

I also considered using a combination of variadic templates and va_list - to somehow pass a variable number of locations from `paramsList`to a variadic function and to pass them on to `vsnprintf`. But i couldn't figure out how to pass certain locations from a given array to a variadic function either.

Update:

I use Visual Studio 2015 to compile on Windows, and GCC 4.9 on Ubuntu.

The error i am getting when trying to compile this code on Linux is: `error: ISO C++ forbids casting to an array type 'va_list {aka __va_list_tag [1]}'`

Comment: Can you include the actual error message you are getting?  It will also be very hard to help you with what little code we can see.

Comment: *This code works fine on Windows* -- It may work "fine" on a certain compiler that creates Windows programs.  It may not work if using another compiler or another version of the same compiler.

Comment: Just to follow up with what PaulMcKenzie said, can you also include what compilers you are using?  So on both Windows and Linux what are you using to compile your code?

Comment: Also, where is it stated that an array of void pointers can be understood or casted to a `va_list`?  This was doomed for failure at some point.  Remove the casts you're doing and recompile the code.  What compiler errors do you get?  If you get errors, please read them and understand what is being stated by the error.

Comment: @Eddge i have updated the original code with additional info

Comment: This feels like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), why do you need to erase all type information about `paramsList`? Can you in anyway meddle with how it is populated?

Answer (score 1):

`va_list` is an *unspecified* type. That means it may be a `void* []` or something else entirely.

That it worked by chance in some cases is just that `va_list` is compatible with `void* []` on one particular platform for one compiler, it is by no means indication that this is legal.

The correct way to deal with this is, unfortunately, to stop using the `printf` family and parse the format string yourself, there is no standard functionality to reach in and fetch the parsed format string to use for yourself.